# How to get all categories for a product in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to have an efficient query which will return all products and their categories from 500k docs collection.

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 4000519129671,
    "category_en": "Home & Garden/Arts,Crafts & Sewing/Soap Making/Bases & Melts",
    "product_title_en": "  Organic White and Clear Transparent Glycerin Soap Base Melt and Pour All Natural Bar For Handmade Soaps - 500g",
    "original_price": 6.64,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674913972323
  },
  {
    "_id": 1005003026993653,
    "category_en": "Tools/Hand Tools/Chisel",
    "product_title_en": " 10 PCS Hand Tool 5/8 Inch Plug Shim &amp; Wedge Wedge &amp; Feather Shims Concrete Rock Stone Splitter Marble Granite",
    "original_price": 44.53,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674938548290
  },
  {
    "_id": 1005003036900899,
    "category_en": "Jewelry & Accessories/Beads & Jewelry Making/Jewelry Tools & Equipments",
    "product_title_en": " 10 Pieces Couple Keychains Heart Shape Silicone Mold for DIY Keychain or Jewelry Earring Necklace Pendant Handmade Craft",
    "original_price": 4.28,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674909849085
  },
  {
    "_id": 1005004276538498,
    "category_en": "Women's Clothing/Plus size clothes/Plus size Tops",
    "product_title_en": " 100% Cotton Plus Size T Shirt L-6XL Tshirt Short Sleeve Women Summer Print Big Size Casual V Neck Oversized T Shirts",
    "original_price": 35.68,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674917854166
  },
  {
    "_id": 32865078275,
    "category_en": "Sports & Entertainment/Hunting/Hunting Bags & Holsters/Pouches",
    "product_title_en": " 1000D Tactical Radio Pouch Walkie Holster Talkie Holder Waist Belt Bag Molle Radio Pouch",
    "original_price": 7.41,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674913287680
  },
  {
    "_id": 33052482619,
    "category_en": "Automobiles & Motorcycles/Car Electronics/Amplifiers/Stereo Amplifiers",
    "product_title_en": " 12V TDA7297 2*15W Digital Stereo Audio Amplifier Motorcycle Power Amplifier Board DIY Kit Dual Channel AMP Module",
    "original_price": 6.33,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674909788976
  },
  {
    "_id": 1005003999710157,
    "category_en": "Women's Clothing/Women Tops/Shirt",
    "product_title_en": " 2022 White Shirt Women Turn Down Collar Casual Teen Gril Student Oversize Shirt Women Loose Short Sleeve Blouse L3208",
    "original_price": 21.4,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674908543193
  },
  {
    "_id": 1005004745078661,
    "category_en": "Home & Garden/Kitchen,Dining & Bar/Teaware/Teapot Trivets",
    "product_title_en": " BORREY Coffee Water Warmer Candle Heating Base Holder Teaware Teapot Warmer Holder Base Tea Japanese Warmer Insulation Base1Pcs",
    "original_price": 26.66,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674901450845
  },
  {
    "_id": 1005004319780627,
    "category_en": "Automobiles & Motorcycles/Interior Accessories/Interior Mirrors",
    "product_title_en": " Car Mirror Portable Makeup Mirror Auto Sun-Shading Visor HD Mirrors Universal Car-styling Automobile Decoration",
    "original_price": 5.74,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674939325594
  },
  {
    "_id": 4000062434454,
    "category_en": "Men's Clothing/Pants/Casual Pants",
    "product_title_en": " Casual Pants Men's Joggers Men Trousers Jogger Man Sweatpants Male Clothing Oversize Sports Streetwear Baggy Wide Summer pants",
    "original_price": 19.91,
    "dateOfCreation": 1674918394349
  }
]
```

It should be a search by product title query which return something like this

```
 products: [{},{}],
 availableCategories: ["Phones", "Tools"], 
 total_records_found: 1000
```

For now I have this query and thinking how to extend it

```
db.products.aggregate([
{$match: { $text: { $search: "Iphone 11 screen protector" } } },
{$sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }},
{$skip: 0 },
{$limit: 10}
])
```

I have also text index for product_title and 1 (ask) index for category_name

[image]

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear about how your sample documents links to your expected output, but you can simply add a `$group` at the end of your aggregation.

```json
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: "Shirt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      score: {
        $meta: "textScore"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "products": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "availableCategories": {
        "$addToSet": "$category_en"
      },
      "total_records_found": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TX8rQ7-W63F)

Comment: this query takes 6 seconds for me in prod db with 500k docs

Comment: @DenysMedvediev what do you expect? For performance issue of text index, you might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455239/14732669)